# "yield from" another generator but after processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield, yield-from

How do we yield from another sub-generator, but with transformation/processing?

for example: in code below, main_gen yields x after transformation using f(x)

```
def f(x):
   return 2*x

def main_gen():
   for x in sub_gen():
      yield f(x)
```

can this be replaced with **yield from** and if so how?

```
def main_gen():
     yield from ***
```

Comment: `yield from map(f, sub_gen())` maybe. But the gain is academic at best

Comment: It's an interesting question, but you won't find anything clearer and more readable than your existing syntax of `for x in sub_gen(): yield f(x)`

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```
def main_gen():
    yield from map(f, sub_gen())
```

But then, why not:

```
def main_gen():
    return map(f, sub_gen())
```

Which is a lazy iterator anyway.

Comment: Importantly, the main benefit of `yield from` (allowing `send` to delegate to the subgenerator instead of being received by the wrapping generator; the reason it was created in the first place, rather than just telling programmers to explicitly `yield` each item like the OP was doing in the first place) is lost when you wrap in `map`, so there is little benefit to using `yield from` over just returning the `map` unless you have some other values to `yield` before or after (where a single return wouldn't work without wrapping, e.g. via `itertools.chain`, making `yield` the less complex option).

Comment: You could write a function `map_gen` and reuse it.

Answer (score 3):

You can always just transform this to a generator expression and `yield from` that:

```py
def main_gen():
    yield from (f(x) for x in sub_gen())
```

Comment: What do you gain from that? The original `for` loop could be written `for x in sub_gen(): yield f(x)` if you want to one-line it, all this does is add a layer of unnecessary wrapping.

Comment: To be honest the original code seems perfectly fine to me. The OP wanted to use `yield from` so...